# MySQL/MariaDB: как выбрать записи из таблицы, не имеющие соответствия в другой?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Дано: две таблицы. В таблице А 100 млн записей. Таблица Б - срез этой таблицы размером в 1 млн записей. Из таблицы А удалены несколько записей, у которых были копии в таблице Б.

Вопрос. Как оптимальнее всего организовать поиск копий удаленных записей в таблице Б?

Некоторые уточнения. Обе таблицы - innodb. СУБД - MariaDB. Триггеров и хранимых процедур нет, очищать таблицу Б нельзя, LEFT JOIN и NOT EXIST использовать не рекомендуется.

Comment: По постановке задачи уточнение: примерно вот таким запросом можно найти все копии удаленных записей: select * from B where not exists in (select * from A)? И вам нужно другое решение ?

Comment: Как реализовать на чистом sql не знаю, но на языке программирования сделал бы следующее: разделил таблицу Б на несколько множеств, по 100 или 1000 в каждом, из таблицы А делал запрос на вхождение в каждое множество, и из результата вычислял удаленные записи.

Comment: "LEFT JOIN и NOT EXIST использовать не рекомендуется" - а чем продиктованы такие _странные_ ограничения?